# Mystery OS X Install program keeps running

Tags: macos, install

I am regularly getting an error message from a program that purports to be an OS X Install program.  I have no idea how this is starting, or where it is from, but it appears after reboots too, and I don't like it.  I'm running the El Capitan 10.11 Beta (15A278b), so there is a possibility it's connected to that.

After trying to update some other apps from the MAS, I get an error message which indicates it's a Yosemite Beta Installer.

Anyone know where this can come from, and how I can stop it?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried just deleting the installer?...

Comment: Exact duplicate, except it doesn't show in my MAS. I'll mark as duplicate when I'm not using the iOS app